# Downgrading from from Unlimited to Enterprise edition in salesforce

Tags: apex, editions

What are the consideration when Downgrading from  from Unlimited to Enterprise edition?Can you please provide your insights if you did a downgrade between instances? Has anyone done this type of downgrade? Is it hard and are there complications or is it just as simple as flipping a switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you review [Salesforce Features and Edition Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US). The Unlimited Edition allows MANY more Validation Rules/object, custom fields/object, custom objects, includes free support, unlimited on-line training, has many more sandboxes, an unlimited number of custom applications (vs a maximum of 10) and much more. See [How to select the right
Sales Cloud edition](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf) for more specifics and additional details that I've not covered as there's a huge difference between the two and much you'll need to check for if you're going to downgrade.

Comment: Is it hard and are there complications or is it just as simple as flipping a switch?

Comment: From my answer above, I'd hope it would be obvious there can be many complications that would require a lot of investigation before making the conversion. Its also something you'd want to discuss with your Account Executive and others who would be impacted with respect to your development & QA team because of the loss of sandboxes. Its not a trivial decision or task.