# Is it possible to downgrade from Unlimited to Enterprise?

Tags: licenses

We are on Sales Cloud Unlimited. Our contract is up and a thorough analysis shows we only need Enterprise. We contacted our sales rep and he said that we cannot downgrade without starting a brand new org and moving everything over manually, which to me seams ludicrous. This [blog post](http://www.asagarwal.com/702/upgrade-downgrade-of-editions-in-salesforce-com) corroborates his answer.

Is what our Salesforce rep telling us a hard fact or is it possible to escalate this request and have our existing org downgraded? Has anyone else been able to downgrade their org? If not, are there any other options to get the reduced license cost that won't require closing down our existing org and creating a new one?

Please note, this question is not about [what to consider when downgrading](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92305/downgrading-from-from-unlimited-to-enterprise-edition-in-salesforce), but whether or not Salesforce is *able to* downgrade our org.

Comment: Got to admit I've never heard of anywhere doing it and if Salesforce refuse to do it either due to technical reasons or commercial ones then you don't have a lot of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can't downgrade the salesforce editions.

Reference : https://certifiedondemand.com/salesforce-com-certified-administrator/user-setup-login-process/different-types-of-salesforce-com-orgs/

Thanks, 
Pavan

Comment: Salesforce confirmed that you cannot downgrade. The lesson is (for us anyways) don't buy more than you absolutely have to, as you will locked in to the higher pricing if re-implementing your customizations in a new org is not feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes True, the Salesforce Org can always be upgraded but cannot be downgraded.
We have also faced the situation. The options in hand in such cases are;

1) Only choose the right kind of Salesforce version and later upgrade, as that's straight forward.

2) To Downgrade, you need to change the Org. 
In this case previous contract with Salesforce is scrapped and entirely a new contract for your Organization is created.

As per new contract you will have a new Salesforce Org id associated.
The data, metadata and integration touch points needs to be taken care properly while migrating stuff to new Org. Integration touch points testing for all the scenarios is a must.

The profile level changes/security settings/user setup has to be done manually again and you must have a complete backup knowledge about user security settings. This portion is not migrated as part of SF version downgrade and setup.

Appropriate change management guidelines to users should be in place before you undertake this exercise as its important. Some issues might linger later which users might escalate.

Overall, with the payoff you can take it ahead. Just have right buyin from business and IT team.

Thanks
Charudatta Thute